# Google API get messages labels and nested labels

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

I have labels in my gmail account that has nested labels e.g like this( Work/programming ).
I am developing on PHP, i have this code for displaying labels list

```
$service_gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail( $client );
$lab = ( ! empty( $_GET['label'] ) ) ? $_GET['label'] : 'INBOX';
$labelsResponse = $service_gmail->users_labels->listUsersLabels('me');
$labels = array_merge($labels, $labelsResponse->getLabels());

<?php if ( ! empty( $labels ) ) { 
        foreach ( $labels as $key => $label ) :
        ?>
             <tr>
                <td width="1%"><span class="num"><?php echo ( $key + 1 ); ?></span></td>
                <td><h5><?php echo $label['name'];?></h5>
                    <small><?php echo $label['type'];?></small></td>
                <td><?php echo $service_gmail->users_labels->get( 'me', $label['id'] )->getMessagesUnread();?></td>
                <td><?php echo $service_gmail->users_labels->get( 'me', $label['id'] )->getMessagesTotal(); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        endforeach;
    }
?>
```

but i want to display nested labels as sublabel of main label, like this

```
   Work
     - accounting
     - programming
     - ......
  Social
     - facebook (Social/facebook)
     - twitter (Social/twitter)
```

So is it possible to do it with no hard coding, so i need all be dynamic ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have 2 arrays $main_labels and $sub_labels. In the foreach loop, you will see if the label name contains character '/'. If it does, you will explode() the label name by '/'. Then you will search in the $main_labels if the first part (before /) already exists. If it does, you will store the second part in $sub_labels. Finally to echo the labels, you will loop over the $main_labels array and inside the loop you will see if $sub_labels[$main_lbl_key] is not empty. If its not empty, there are subcategories and you have to write another loop over $sub_labels[$main_lbl_key] to echo them.

For example like:

```
<?php

$service_gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail( $client );
$lab = ( ! empty( $_GET['label'] ) ) ? $_GET['label'] : 'INBOX';
$labelsResponse = $service_gmail->users_labels->listUsersLabels('me');
$labels = array_merge($labels, $labelsResponse->getLabels());

$main_labels = $sub_labels = array();

function ifMainLabelExists($lbl) {
    global $main_labels;
    foreach ($main_labels as $k => $l) {
        if (strcmp($lbl['name'], $l) === 0) {
            return $k;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

if ( ! empty( $labels ) ) { 
    foreach ( $labels as $key => $label ) {
        if (strpos($label['name'], '/') !== false) {
            $label_parts = explode('/', $label['name']); // break label name at  character '/'
            if (count($label_parts) > 1) {
                $m = ifMainLabelExists($label_parts[0]);
                if ($m !== -1) { // main label already exists
                    $label['name'] = $label_parts[1];
                    $sub_labels[$m][] = $label;
                } else { // main label does not exist already
                    $label['name'] = $label_parts[0];
                    $main_labels[] = $label;
                    $m = count($main_labels) - 1; // will be inserted at last index

                    $label['name'] = $label_parts[1];
                    $sub_labels[$m][] = $label;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $main_labels[] = $label;
        }
    }
}

// now echo them
```